# Capture Jython output as it happens

Tags: java, python, ajax, jython

I am developing a web app for teaching Python, and one of the issues I have to solve is how to capture the standard output from Jython interpreter, the moment it is complemented.

Currently I capture the output in `StringBuilder` object, but this approach lets me get the output only when the code finished running:

```
PythonInterpreter interp = new PythonInterpreter(null, new PySystemState());
StringWriter out = new StringWriter();
interp.setOut(out);
interp.exec(pyScript);
String outputStr = out.toString();
```

What I'd like to have, is that after the runnable code is received from the browser, the interpreter keeps running in the background. If the code is such that takes time to run, but the output is captured and stored in the database, letting an Ajax code continuously receive updates about what is outputted.

Comment: Have you tried calling exec and reading from the OutputStream from different threads?

Comment: No, I haven't. I had this idea that I could create my own OutputStream class that would mischievously commit to the database whatever is written to it, but I hoped to avoid it, as there are enough methods to implement to discourage me from doing it. There is also PythonInterpreter.setOut(PyObject outStream) method, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html which is what you would use if you were to read from the output stream in another thread.  Bare in mind that writing to the database in the same thread will probably cause your python code to block (which may be acceptable of course).

Comment: Thanks, the python code blocking is a legitimate concern, but in this particular case I can cut the stream in chunks and save to database in regular time intervals, as the Ajax update is not immediate anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Man, writing my own implementation of OutputStream turned out to be the way to go. It was enough to implement just write() and flush() methods. Something along the lines of this:

```
public class DBOutputStream extends OutputStream
{
    private String buffer;
    private DBConnClass db;

    public DBOutputStream (DBConnClass dbConn)
    {
        buffer = "";
        db = dbConn;
    }

    public void write(int b)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
        bytes[0] = (byte) (b & 0xff);
        buffer = buffer + new String(bytes);

        if (buffer.endsWith("\n"))
        {
            buffer = buffer.substring (0, buffer.length () - 1);
            flush ();
        }
    }   
    public void flush()
    {
        // Commit the buffer to db here
        buffer = "";
    }
}
```

I guess this is more stable than reading the OutputStream from another thread. Now it's enough to have only one thread, the one where the interpreter is running.